# Create hovering popup window

Tags: popup

Im switching from nvim to emacs and wanted to know if I could somehow build a hovering buffer like telescope. I know there is consult which has the same capabilities as Telescope, but I want to know how I can create a popup window and style it like telescopes.

How can I create a custom Popup window which hovers and can be customized?

Comment: What you like to achieve is showing completion candidates in a [child frame](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Child-Frames.html). The section [Child frames and Popups](https://github.com/minad/vertico#child-frames-and-popups) of the Vertico README (the completion UI most often used i.c.w. the Consult pakcage), describes how to achieve that.